# Detecting HIDPI settings in JavaFX application

Tags: linux, javafx, hidpi

Currently, I am using `JDK 15` and `JavaFX 15` in `GNOME/Wayland` on Linux on a 4K monitor. It appears that the produced apps cannot detect my 200% upscale setting.

When researching I came up with [this bug ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8219182) that suggests moving to JavaFX 11, which is no longer working.

How should I detect and force upscale my JavaFX applications?

Answer (score 0):

The ticket does not suggest downgrading to JavaFX 11. It suggest upgrading from 8. As you are already using 15 that's fine. Nevertheless I would suggest to try the latest EA release of JavaFX which is 17-ea+2 at the time of this writing, in order to see whether your problem has been fixed already. If not submit a bug report.
There recently was a discussion on the mailing list about such a bug:
https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2021-February/028827.html
Maybe that helps.